# Icons size animation onPressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have BottomAppBar with Row Icons.

```
BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(),
              IconButton(),
              IconButton(),
            ],
          ))
```

I want to make an smooth animation so that when you click on an icon, it shrinks and then returns to its original size. I would call it a tap effect. I know a way to do it through a bunch of animationcontroller, but is there any way to make it easier, like AnimatedSize or else?

Something like this:

0: IconSize = 20.0

1: onPressed: IconSize = 15.0

2: IconSize = 20.0

Comment: Have you tried to use plugins?

Comment: @Marat unfortunately I can't do that

Comment: Then I don't think that it is possible without a bunch of AnimationControllers

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) widget to do that and wrap it into a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and change the width and the height of the container like this:

```
bool selected = false;

BottomAppBar(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(child: AnimatedContainer(child: Icon(), width: selected ? 15.0 : 20.0), onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    selected = !selected;
  });
},),
          AnimatedContainer(child: Icon(), width: selected ? 15.0 : 20.0),
          AnimatedContainer(child: Icon(), width: selected ? 15.0 : 20.0),
        ],
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with an [AnimatedBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html), a [TweenSequence](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html) and an [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html). The official documentation of the `AnimatedBuilder` explains the setup very well (even with a video).

Your `TweenSequence` could look like this:

```
final Animation<double> animation = TweenSequence(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 20.0, end: 15.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
      weight: 50.0,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 15.0, end: 20.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
      weight: 50.0,
    ),
  ],
).animate(myAnimationController);
```